# How to set parameter List in retrofit2

Tags: java, android, parameters, retrofit2

I get problem about set parameter in retrofit2

I would like to set `group_id` and `user_id`

```
public class ChatRequest {

    private String group_id;
    private List<Userbean> users;

    public String getGroup_id() {
        return group_id;
    }

    public void setGroup_id(String group_id) {
        this.group_id = group_id;
    }

    public List<Userbean> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<Userbean> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }


    public static class Userbean {


        private int user_id;

        public int getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }
    }
}
```

and my retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest();
chatRequest.setGroup_id("dsdfjlds9u");
chatRequest.setUsers ///// How to set user_id = 8(int)
```

How to set user_id = 8 ??

I have no idea to set it

thanks for your help!

Comment: Userbean  mUserbean =new Userbean();  mUserbean.setUser_id(8); chatRequest.setUsers(mUserbean );

Comment: List<Userbean> users .. create list and set id

Comment: Can you paste a little example of your JSON?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel if i setuser_id = 8 and 25 How to set chatRequest.setUsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest();
chatRequest.setGroup_id("dsdfjlds9u");
UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
userBean.setUser_Id(8);
chatRequest.setUsers(Collections.singletonList(userBean));
```

Comment: thanks , I have one question, If I want to set setUser_Id more than 1. How to set it because your code is not set more than1

Comment: List<UserBean> userBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
    userBean.setUser_Id(8);
   userBeanList.add(userBean);

With the add () method you are adding the elements to the list in succession.

Answer (score 0):

Steps Need to follow to set user_id
* Need to initialize a object for ChatRequest
* Declare the list which contains Userbean class as params
* Initialize the Userbean class's object
* Set the user id as 8 using setter class
* Add the user to Userbean list
* Set the Userbean list to ChatRequest

```
int user_id=8;
ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest();
List<ChatRequest.Userbean> userbeanList =new List<ChatRequest.Userbean>() {
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return false;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Iterator<ChatRequest.Userbean> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return new Object[0];
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(@NonNull T[] ts) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean add(ChatRequest.Userbean userbean) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(@NonNull Collection<?> collection) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends ChatRequest.Userbean> collection) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int i, @NonNull Collection<? extends ChatRequest.Userbean> collection) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(@NonNull Collection<?> collection) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(@NonNull Collection<?> collection) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void clear() {
    }
    @Override
    public ChatRequest.Userbean get(int i) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public ChatRequest.Userbean set(int i, ChatRequest.Userbean userbean) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(int i, ChatRequest.Userbean userbean) {
    }
    @Override
    public ChatRequest.Userbean remove(int i) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public ListIterator<ChatRequest.Userbean> listIterator() {
        return null;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListIterator<ChatRequest.Userbean> listIterator(int i) {
        return null;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<ChatRequest.Userbean> subList(int i, int i1) {
        return null;
    }
};
ChatRequest.Userbean userBean=new ChatRequest.Userbean();
userBean.setUser_id(user_id);
userbeanList.add(userBean);
chatRequest.setUsers(userbeanList);
Log.e("Users",chatRequest.getUsers().toString());
Log.e("Users id",String.valueOf(userBean.getUser_id()));
```